# Snowflake function with variable as parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-cursor

I am trying to find out the object level dependencies (tables and/or other views) of the views created in my work schema.
My userid/role does not have access to ACCOUNT_USAGE because of organizational policy.
So, I query the function GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES to get the base object information for every view. The dependency can be multi-level, with views dependent on other views and finally on one or more tables.

I thought of writing a cursor based query to scan the schema for all views and with these view names, generate the list of dependencies and store in a table.

But the cursor is throwing error, which I am not able to solve :

```
Uncaught exception of type 'STATEMENT_ERROR' on line 10 at position 8 : SQL compilation error: Object 'TEST_DB.MY_SCHEMA.V_VW_NM' does not exist or not authorized.
```

Can I use a cursor variable inside a function ( GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES ) ?

Below is the code :

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE TEST_DB.MY_SCHEMA.OBJ_LINEAGE ( ref_obj_nm  VARCHAR );

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
    $$
    DECLARE
        v_vw_nm     VARCHAR;
        cur_vw_nm   CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_type = 'VIEW';
    BEGIN
        FOR c_vw_nm_rec IN cur_vw_nm 
        DO
            v_vw_nm := c_vw_nm_rec.table_name;
        
            INSERT INTO OBJ_LINEAGE ( ref_obj_nm )
            SELECT 
                 '('||LOWER(referenced_object_type)||') '||referenced_schema_name||'.'||referenced_object_name
            FROM 
                  TABLE
                  (  GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES
                     (  
                        database_name => 'TEST_DB'
                       ,schema_name   => 'MY_SCHEMA'
                       ,object_name   => v_vw_nm
                     )
                  ) 
            ORDER BY 
                 referenced_schema_name, referenced_object_name;
    
            RETURN 1;
        END FOR;
    END;
    $$
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use dynamic sql.

Below is sample code.

```
DECLARE
    v_vw_nm     VARCHAR;
    cur_vw_nm   CURSOR FOR SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_type = 'VIEW';
    sql_query VARCHAR;
BEGIN
    FOR c_vw_nm_rec IN cur_vw_nm 
    DO
        v_vw_nm := c_vw_nm_rec.table_name;
    
        
        sql_query := 'INSERT INTO OBJ_LINEAGE ( ref_obj_nm )
        SELECT 
             ''(''||LOWER(referenced_object_type)||'') ''||referenced_schema_name||''.''||referenced_object_name
        FROM 
              TABLE
              (  GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES
                 (  
                    database_name => ''TEST_DB''
                   ,schema_name   => ''MY_SCHEMA''
                   ,object_name   => '||:v_vw_nm ||'
                 )
              ) 
        ORDER BY 
             referenced_schema_name, referenced_object_name';
        execute immediate :sql_query;

        RETURN 1;
    END FOR;
END;
```